# Is $\text{esssup}_{t \in [0,T]}\max(f(t), g(t)) \leq \max (\text{esssup}_{t \in [0,T]} f(t), \text{esssup}_{t \in [0,T]} g(t))?$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ and $g$ be functions defined on $[0,T]$ into $\mathbb{R}$ (not necessarily continuous).

Is it true that $$\text{esssup}_{t \in [0,T]}\max(f(t), g(t)) \leq \max (\text{esssup}_{t \in [0,T]} f(t), \text{esssup}_{t \in [0,T]} g(t))?$$

The right hand side picks out the biggest value either function takes. I think both sides are equal, am I right?

Comment: What happened when you tried to prove it?

Comment: I concluded that the statement holds with exact equality. I just want to check I am not mistaken due to the subtleties with null sets.